# Property not found on String

Tags: actionscript

So i am trying to make a word jumlbe sort of program but i am running into some difficulties with the function for shuffelling the words

So i tried:

```
function klikk(evt){
var i:int = 0;
var ordet:String = inntastetOrd;
var lengde:int = ordet.length;
var tall:int = 0;
var karakter:String;

for(i=0;i<ordet.length; i++)
{
    tall = Math.random() *ordet.length;
    karakter = ordet[tall];
    ordet[i] = ordet[tall];
    ordet[tall] = karakter;
}
```

But i am getting: "Error #1069: Property "some value" not found on String and there is no default value."

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to chose a letter in a `String`, you need to transform this `String` into `Array` with the [split](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split%28%29) method.

**For example:**

```
var letters:String = "word";
trace(letters[2]); // Error #1069
var a:Array = letters.split(""); // w,o,r,d
trace(a[2]); // r
```